# Mapping on a finite set and eventually periodic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be a finite set containing $n$ elements, and $g:X \mapsto X$ be a map. Show that the sequence $g^k(c)$, where $k \in \mathbb Z^+$ is eventually periodic.

Does this imply that $g^k$, $k \in \mathbb Z^+$ is eventually periodic?

What I have done so far:

Well, certainly, a map needs to send every element in the domain to an element in the codomain. Suppose that $g^k(c)$ is not eventually periodic. This can only imply that c is mapped to more than 1 element in the codomain. Hence, it contradicts the fact that it is a function and a map hence $g^k(c)$ must be eventually periodic.

However, I am very unclear about why the question asked "Does this imply that $g^k$ is eventually periodic?". Since $g^k(c)$ is eventually periodic, doesn't this automatically mean that $g^k$ is eventually periodic?

I am not sure if I am on the right track for the first part of the question but any hints or suggestions would be helpful too!

Comment: For a fixed $c$ the sequence $(g^k(c))_{k_\ge 1}$ is periodic after some point/index with the following argument: Let $n$ be the cardinality of $X$, consider the first repetition among the first $n+1$ terms of the sequence. Such a repetition exists, the principle of Dirichlet. (It is important to get a clear argument for the repetition, now the second question has a quick chance.) Consider now an infinite set, maybe the following one, the disjoint union $X$ of some sets $A_k$, where $A_k$ has $k$ elements. Let $g$ act on $A_k$ by a cyclic permutation. Then *pointwise* we have repetions, but...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint for the second part:* The set of functions $X \to X$ is finite.

Comment: Can I use the argument that because the set of functions is finite, then the order of the functions must be finite. Hence, it must be that it will be eventually periodic?

Comment: Exactly........